# Recommendations about presenting data to user

Tags: azure, data-visualization, databricks, reporting, business-intelligence

I am a beginner of data analytic solutions, and working on a project to migrate our data solutions to Azure, with Azure datalake, data factory, databricks to be the pipeline.

But it is hard to choose the right solution for visualizing data(self-service for creating dashboard) and allow user to download an canned report (Excel, txt file) for external integration. Do you guys have any recommendations?

Currently we are using Business Object Enterprise(BOE) & crystal report, but we would like to find a new & modern way to do that.

Comment: Try https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/business-intelligence/#products

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already have Crystal Reports, the canned reports aspect is probably already solved. So the question boils down to adding self-service access to slicing and dicing data.

For a free solution, you can start with ***Excel Pivot Tables***. You can boost that approach by adding ***Power Query*** and ***Power Pivot***, which are free. To avoid the need to learn Power Query, there are 3rd-party tools that can take data from your Crystal reports, and generate/refresh excel pivot tables, Power Pivots, or dashboards.

If you need to provide web access to this type of functionality, plus very nice data visualizations, then ***Power BI*** is a popular choice. But [subscription cost](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/) starts at ~$10/month per user.

***Tableau*** is another popular choice for powerful data visualizations. But it is even more expensive than Power BI. Here's a link to [pricing info](https://www.betterbuys.com/bi/tableau-pricing/).

Disclosure: I'm the developer of the solution discussed next. It allows you to **automate/schedule exporting data from your Crystal reports or Excel workbooks into web pages that give users self-serve as well as pre-defined interactive web pivot tables/charts**. Here's a link to a [video demonstrating that technique](https://youtu.be/Vwt8TXdKU7A?t=483). It requires no web application. All you need is a shared folder, web folder, or SharePoint. Cost of a license is $300 and it never expires.